# Make ConEmu.exe the new default cmd.exe

Tags: command-line, cmd.exe

I'm trying to replace the dreaded Win 7 cmd.exe with the much more useful [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/). However I cannot seem to be able to make it the default command line tool.

I want any application, anywhwere, anytime it starts cmd.exe to instead use ConEmu.exe.

How do I go about that?

Comment: Rename `cmd.exe.` to `cmd.exe.old` and copy `conemu.exe` to `cmd.exe`?

Comment: Do not do that! Read docs instead! https://conemu.github.io/en/DefaultTerminal.html

Comment: And don't mix terms... https://conemu.github.io/en/Delusions.html